# SQL Query - Finding Current log file usage for one database

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2000

I want to set up some monitoring software that will generate an SMNP trap if a database log file goes beyond about 95% usage. It can only look at the first result in the first column of an SQL query, so what I'm looking for is an SQL Query which will just return the percentage figure ONLY in the result - eg, 95

I've found several different ways of doing similar things, but all return table heading etc, whereas I just want the figure. It'll be running this query every hour so nothing too intensive. I'm running SQL version 8.

Thanks, Mike

Comment: You mean an SNMP trap, right? Can you show the query you tried that returns additional information?

Comment: Yes sorry, SNMP :) This is what I've tried, but ists all the DB's with the heading:   SELECT instance_name AS 'master', 

    MAX(CASE
           WHEN counter_name = 'Percent Log Used'
               THEN cntr_value
           ELSE 0
       END) AS 'Percent Log Used'
  
FROM sysperfinfo
WHERE counter_name IN
   (
       'Percent Log Used'
   )
  AND instance_name != '_total'
GROUP BY instance_name

Comment: So you'll need to explain how you want to calculate the average for the whole instance. Those % are per database, so if you have one database that's 10GB and one that's 10MB, those % mean very different things.

Comment: thats right, I just want to monitor the log file size for one database, not all of them

Comment: Out of curiosity, what are you going to do when this specific database hits 95% log space used?

Comment: Its an indication that one of the maintenance jobs has failed to run

Comment: So why not check the status of the maintenance job? Log can max out in between instances of the maintenance job but perhaps you're not doing yourself any favors by relying on auto grow or having a maintenance job that presumably does what, checkpoint and shrink file?

Answer (score 0):

You could write a query against the OS DMVs to get just the single value you're looking for.

Not sure if this will work for SQL Server 2000, but I know it works as far back as SQL Server 2005.  It also requires that performance counters are enabled on the host server (i.e. OS, not just SQL Server).

This query should do the trick:

```
SELECT cntr_value as PercentUsed
FROM sys.dm_os_performance_counters
WHERE counter_name = 'Percent Log Used'
  AND instance_name = 'your_database_name'
```